# Exclude not working for Rack::SSL

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra, rack

I currently have a sinatra project that I am trying to add SSL to so I tried to add `Rack::SSL` which worked fine, but I'd like to have it disabled in development mode.

```
class Blog < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::SSL, :exclude => lambda { |env| ENV['RACK_ENV'] != 'production' }
...
```

This is the code I have and ENV['RACK_ENV'] is returning 'development' when I pry, but for some reason when I try to hit my site locally it's still trying to redirect to https.

Comment: If you only want to enable it in production, wouldn’t it be clearer to use a [`configure` block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration)? Something like `configure :production do use Rack::SSL; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got caught out by this last week. Turns out I'd enabled HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) too, which meant once a cookie for the site had been served over HTTPS the browser would prevent any future requests to the non-HTTPS version of the site.

Thought I'd mention it just incase you've got the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works, chrome just had the redirect cached from before I added this so I thought it wasn't working. Worked fine in an incognito window.

Comment: There is also a setting in Chrome's dev tools to turn off caching while you've got the dev tools open.